# Python return filepath/filename of most recent csv file stored in directory

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder that csv files are stored in.  How can I get python to search this folder and return the filename of the most recent file created. e.g search C:\CSVfiles  and return filename in the form of  C:\CSVfiles\CSVmostrecent.csv? I'm using windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter to the `max()` function:

```
import os
import glob

filename = max(glob.iglob("c:/csvfiles/*.csv"), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Depending on your intention, you might want to use [`os.path.getctime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) instead of [`os.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime).